# When I run test in selenium using java, the alert gets closed but in code it shows failure

Tags: selenium-webdriver, alert

Adding details

In my test I am trying to click 'ok' button on the alert popup for which I am using .accept() function . and while execution , the script is able to click on ok button successfully as I can see in the application functionality but in the detailed report ,the one generated by eclipse it shows the particular test step as failure.
I am using   Alert myAlert = driver.switchTo().alert(); 
              myAlert.accept();

Comment: This question lacks sufficient detail, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info.

Comment: Adding detail

In my test I am trying to click 'ok' button  on the alert popup for which I am using .accep() function . and while execution , the script is able to click on ok buttton successfully as I can see in the application functionality but in the detailed report it shows the particular test  step as failure.

Comment: What is the failure reason mentioned in the report?

Comment: @Rashmi you need to edit and update the question, not add comments to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to you, you are able to accept the alert but test step is showing exception in console : 
You can catch the exception and proceed further with your next steps:
Below is the code :

```
        try {
            Alert myAlert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            myAlert.accept();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("######### Successfully Accepted Alert ################");
        }
// here proceed with your next steps.
```

Hope it will help you out.